Fresco 3.4.0 is there replacement for PriorityNetworkFetcher
I am upgrading from version 2.6 to 3.4.0.
Given the recent removal of PriorityNetworkFetcher, are there suitable replacements or workarounds within the current infrastructure to accomplish its original functionality?
